# Completing the square step for quadratic equation

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I’m confused about the third step In the proof of the quadratic equation with the form
$$
ax^2 + bx + c = 0. 
$$
In the third step it is added $\bigl(\frac{b}{2a}\bigr)^2$ to both sides to complete the square, and it would make sense if it was geometrically possible.

[Screenshot of derivation of quadratic formula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiCtb.jpg)

I mean, if it was $ax^2 + bx - c = 0$, that is, $ax^2 + bx = c$, we can think of it as a square with both sides $x$, and a (maybe) rectangle with side $\frac{b}{a}$ and the other $x$, and they have an area of $\frac{c}{a}$.

[image: Square and rectangle.]

so we can complete that square, and if we continue the rest of following algebra steps, we get a quite similar result that is,
$$
x = \frac{-b±\sqrt{b^2+4ac}}{2a}
$$
So...
Did they just apply the concept of completing the square to find a square with a negative area? is a negative area possible?

Comment: "... and it would make sense if it was geometrically possible. " Why? Algebra doesn't need a geometric interpretation to be valid.

Comment: @jjagmath But isn't completing the square a geometric step?

Comment: Why would adding a number to both sides of an equation be a geometric step?

Comment: Arabic mathematicians (Al-Kwarizmi?) discounted the solution which was not geometric, in the way you say.  The method had its history in literally completing a square figure, but the algebra does not require it.

Comment: Have you learned about imaginary numbers?  If so, think about how a square with sides of length 'i' has an area of -1.  Mathematicians would not have learned to use imaginary numbers if they had only considered problems with physical geometric interpretations.

Comment: @jjagmath Right! I just always thought about it as a square and a rectangle, so we cut that rectangle into half, then rearranging it, so we added a square to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A square **in the context of algebra** is an expression of the form $u^2$ for some $u$. To complete the square is *a technique* to add a (possibly negative, i.e. subtract) quantity to make the expression a square. Since we know that
$$
\biggl( x + \frac{b}{2a} \biggr)^2 = x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} 
$$
is a square *by definition* with $u = x + \smash[b]{\dfrac{b}{2a}}$, the natural step in this derivation is to add
$\smash[b]{\biggl( \dfrac{b}{2a} \biggr)^2}$
to both sides of the equation to complete it!